# powershell to write html with php elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, powershell

I am trying to write an html page using powershell.  The html code I am using also has javascript and php elements.  All of the code gets written to the file I am writing with powershell, but when I view it in a browser, it just shows me a blank page.  What am I missing?

```
$htmlexport = @"
<?php include("top.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/weather/js/hanis_min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="HAniS.setup('http://127.0.0.1/weather/models/RAP/RAP-USA-PTYPE-config.txt','handiv')">
  <div id="main-copy-bot" style="text-align:left">
    <br>
    <div id="main-copy">
      <center>
        <table width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
          <tr>
            <th><?php
            include("ltmenu-rap.php");
            ?></th>
            <th>
              <div id="handiv" style="width:1100px;height:825 background-color:#808080;"></div><br>
            </th>
            <th><?php
            include("rtmenu.php");
            ?></th>
          </tr>
        </table><?php
        include("bottom.php");
        ?>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
"@

$htmlexport | Out-File C:\xampp\htdocs\weather\testbatch5.php
```

Comment: "but when I view it in a browser" - your browser doesn't execute `php` - that's a server-side language

Comment: PowerShell probably shouldn't be tagged here as the PowerShell part works. The only thing PowerShell-related that could come up would be the encoding of the output file.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, the files are on a local server running PHP.  If I take the code and manually save it to a file myself, it works fine.

Comment: Try `Out-File C:\xampp\htdocs\weather\testbatch5.php -Encoding UTF8` or `Out-File C:\xampp\htdocs\weather\testbatch5.php -Encoding Default`.

Comment: Yes, -Encoding UTF8 did the trick.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to manually save the file with success but using PowerShell's `Out-File` fails, the issue is likely with encoding. The [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1) default encoding in Windows PowerShell (version 5.1 or lower) is `Unicode` which is `UTF-16le`. Saving the file manually on Windows is likely using a different encoding like the system's active code page (usually ANSI) or `UTF-8` (with BOM in Windows). You may simply use the `-Encoding` switch to specify the encoding.

```
# Encodes in UTF8 with BOM in Windows PowerShell
$htmlexport | Out-File C:\xampp\htdocs\weather\testbatch5.php -Encoding UTF8
```

Note that in PowerShell Core (v6+), the default encoding of [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1) is UTF8 with no BOM (`utf8NoBOM`).